# How to have a like/dislike mechanism with Django model

Tags: django, django-models

I have implemented a comment model with my Django application. Now I want to associate it with a `CommentLike` model where I intend to keep track of like/dislike reaction from the user.

Should I keep a track of like/dislike in the `CommentLike` model, or should I have another model `CommentDislike` ?

What is the best way to have a like/dislike model and keep this in a structured way ?

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(max_length=255, default = uuid.uuid4)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000, default="")
    likes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    commentinguser = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class CommentLike(models.Model):
    likinguser = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create another model. You could have something like this:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    # ...
    commentinguser = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class CommentFeedback(models.Model):
    FEEDBACK_OPTIONS = (
        ('L', 'Like'),
        ('D', 'Dislike'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='feedback')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=FEEDBACK_OPTIONS)
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='feedback')
```

Then, you can access all of the likes for a specific comment by writing:

```
Comment.objects.filter(feedback='L') # To get the likes
```

The same with getting the activity of a user:

```
User.objects.filter(feedback='L') # To get every comment that a user liked
```

With this approach, you can also add something like the stackoverflow claps or any kind of other feedback by just writing it in `FEEDBACK_OPTIONS`.

Comment: Good answer ... Suggestion of having CommentFeedback model name is also quite clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

> DB Writes can be heavy, Reads should be Fast.

In any case, having the `likes` count in the Comment model and using 'F' query to increment/decrement the counter will solve most of your future problems. So good decision there already.

Have another column `type` with two Choices - ['like', 'dislike'] in the CommentLike model itself and a `unique_together = ('likinguser', 'comment')` constraint.

So your query to get Comment Likers for a comment with id = comment_id, will be:

```
User.objects.filter(
id__in=CommentLike.objects.filter(comment=comment_id, type='like').values_list('likinguser', flat=True)
)
```

For dislikers,

```
User.objects.filter(
id__in=CommentLike.objects.filter(comment=comment_id, type='dislike').values_list('likinguser', flat=True)
)
```

Comment: Yes, but what about getting only a single like from the particular user is important, there needs to be a track of each like action, either it is like or dislike. So counting the likes in comment is not sufficient.

Comment: It’s not sufficient, I agree. But counting with joins is costly. Hence you do both. Keep a total like counter in comment model, and individual entries, for other purposes.

Comment: medium.com work as you suggested, you can like as many times as you press. youtube does not let a single user to like more than once, which seems more accurate and correct.

Comment: @SuperEye I am not saying update the counter every time, that totally depends on your business logic/requirement on when you update it. My point being you keep the counter for your LIST API to be fast. So let's say, You have 10,000 comments on a video, and you need to show the likes counter in the UI. Without keeping a counter with a comment, you would need to make 2 Count queries for every Comment and take the difference of likes and dislikes. That will be way too slow and at high scale, it will put your SQL CPU at immense loads, which could have been easily avoided.

Comment: so the timing of your Counter updation, will depend if the DB entry in the CommentLike / CommentFeedback model was successful in the Youtube case. If the unique constraint is passed, the entry for like/dislike is made...update the counter. You can have entire operation as an SQL atomic Transaction too.

Comment: That is agreed, in order to show the comment total likes/dislikes there is already a counter in the Comment model, which is equivalent to your comment. No need to count it every time, true.